# How to count black pixel images in 3 channel image?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, tensorflow, keras

I want to know how to find black pixel image In 3 channel image.I used cv2.countNonZero() to find non black pixels so that I can subtract from total number of pixels , but it works only for single channel image. Which one should be used Numpy or Opencv or keras and how?

Answer (score 0):

Using OpenCV, you can simply do the following:

```py
import cv2

# Load input image
input = cv2.imread('images/colors.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

# Mask black pixels
mask = 255 * ((input[:, :, 0] == 0) & (input[:, :, 1] == 0) & (input[:, :, 2] == 0))

# Count black pixel
print("Total number of pixels in image: " + str(input.shape[0] * input.shape[1]))
print("Number of black pixels in image: " + str(cv2.countNonZero(mask)))
```

This is my input image:

[image: Input image]

This is the generated mask of black pixels:

[image: Mask of black pixels]

And, this is the output:

```
Total number of pixels in image: 1474560
Number of black pixels in image: 258745
```